# Music app that reads external storage audio is working on emulator and not working on real devices

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-external-storage, android-music-player

I have a list view that displays all the songs in my device in the application, then when I click on the song another activity opens where you can play the song, on emulator when I click on the song in the list it takes me to the other activity and I can play and hear the song, but on real device I'm not getting any error but when I select an item from the list, I get the name and artist of the song, but when i click on play it doesn't work, I don't hear sound nor can I jump to middle of song etc..

the list is like this:

[image]

When clicked:

[image]

I'm using media player  to read the audio files, and the code for my main activity is:

```
public class MusicPlayerOffline extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tvTime,tvDuration,tvTitle,tvArtist;
    SeekBar seekBarTime,seekBarVolume;
    Button btnPlay;

    MediaPlayer musicPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_music_player_offline);
        Songs song = (Songs) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("song");
        tvTime=findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        tvDuration=findViewById(R.id.tvDuration);
        seekBarTime=findViewById(R.id.seekBarTime);
        seekBarVolume=findViewById(R.id.seekBarVolume);
        btnPlay=findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
        tvTitle=findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvArtist=findViewById(R.id.tvArtist);

        tvTitle.setText(song.getTitle());
        tvArtist.setText(song.getArtist());

        musicPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            musicPlayer.setDataSource(song.getPath());
            musicPlayer.prepare();
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        musicPlayer.setLooping(true);
        musicPlayer.seekTo(0);
        musicPlayer.setVolume(0.5f, 0.5f);

        String duration = millisecondsToString(musicPlayer.getDuration());
        tvDuration.setText(duration);

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this );

        seekBarVolume.setProgress(50);
        seekBarVolume.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                float volume = progress /100f;
                musicPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        seekBarTime.setMax(musicPlayer.getDuration());
        seekBarTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser){
                    musicPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (musicPlayer != null){
                    if (musicPlayer.isPlaying()){
                        try {
                            final double current = musicPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                            final String elapsdTime = millisecondsToString((int) current);

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    tvTime.setText(elapsdTime);
                                    seekBarTime.setProgress((int) current);
                                }
                            });

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        }catch (InterruptedException e){}
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }// end main

    public String millisecondsToString(int time){
        String elapsedTime = "";
        int minutes = time / 1000 / 60;
        int seconds = time / 1000 % 60;
        elapsedTime = minutes+":";
        if (seconds < 10){
            elapsedTime += "0";
        }
        elapsedTime += seconds;

        return elapsedTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.btnPlay){
            if (musicPlayer.isPlaying()){
                // is playing
                musicPlayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }else {
                // on pause
                musicPlayer.start();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home){
            finish();
            if (musicPlayer.isPlaying()){
                musicPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The code for my listviewmusic activity from where I retrieve title artist and audio is:

```
public class ListMusicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 99;

    ArrayList<Songs> songArrayList;
    ListView tvSongs;
    SongsAdapter songsAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_music);

        tvSongs = findViewById(R.id.tvSongs);

        songArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        songsAdapter = new SongsAdapter(this, songArrayList);
        tvSongs.setAdapter(songsAdapter);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }else {
            // you have permission to read from external storage
            getSongs();
        }

        tvSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Songs song = songArrayList.get(position);
                Intent openMusicPlayer = new Intent(ListMusicActivity.this, MusicPlayerOffline.class);
                openMusicPlayer.putExtra("song", song);
                startActivity(openMusicPlayer);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION){
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                getSongs();
            }
        }
    }

    private void getSongs() {
        // read songs from phone
        ContentResolver contentProvider = getContentResolver();
        Uri songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        Cursor songCursor = contentProvider.query(songUri,null,null,null,null);

        if (songCursor != null && songCursor.moveToNext()) {

            int indexTitle = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
            int indexArtist = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
            int indexData = songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);

            do {
                String title = songCursor.getString(indexTitle);
                String artist = songCursor.getString(indexArtist);
                String path = songCursor.getString(indexData);
                songArrayList.add(new Songs(title, artist, path));
            }while (songCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        songsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My adapter:

```
public class SongsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Songs> {

    public SongsAdapter(@NonNull Context context,  @NonNull List<Songs> objects) {
        super(context,0, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_song, null);

        TextView tvTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        TextView tvArtist = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvArtist);

        Songs song = getItem(position);
        tvTitle.setText(song.getTitle());
        tvArtist.setText(song.getArtist());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I have no idea why it's not working, I don't get any error in the logcat, the music just doesn't start, it stays frozen at 0:00, and I cant jump to middle of it etc, although the name and artist name get obtained successfully just no audio

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.smallacademy.authenticatorapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <activity android:name=".ListMusicActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MusicPlayerOffline" />
        <activity android:name=".MusicplayerOnline" />
        <activity android:name=".Musicplayer" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Admin_crud_Illness"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Admin_crud_food"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".CaloriesCounterAdmin" />
        <activity android:name=".Admin_addIllness" />
        <activity android:name=".Admin_addfood" />
        <activity android:name=".WaterInfo" />
        <activity android:name=".WaterIntake" />
        <activity android:name=".Share" />
        <activity android:name=".Weather_Act" />
        <activity android:name=".CalorieCounter" />
        <activity android:name=".FetchFeedbacks" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminHome" />
        <activity android:name=".FeedBack" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminDel" />
        <activity android:name=".UpdateData" />
        <activity android:name=".Fetchdata" />
        <activity android:name=".Admin_add" />
        <activity android:name=".BmiInfo" />
        <activity android:name=".AdminAct" />
        <activity android:name=".Loseweight_nutrition" />
        <activity android:name=".Maintainweight_nutrition" />
        <activity android:name=".Overweight_nutrition" />
        <activity android:name=".Nutrition" />
        <activity android:name=".CalmMood" />
        <activity android:name=".AnnoyedMood" />
        <activity android:name=".AngryMood" />
        <activity android:name=".SadMood" />
        <activity android:name=".HappyMood" />
        <activity android:name=".MoodFeature" />
        <activity android:name=".Calendar" />
        <activity android:name=".Alarm" />
        <activity
            android:name=".StopWatch"
            android:parentActivityName=".Home" />
        <activity android:name=".Splash">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Exercice"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
        <activity android:name=".BMI_Calculator" />
        <activity android:name=".Home" />
        <activity android:name=".EditProfile" />
        <activity android:name=".Login" />
        <activity android:name=".Register" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="preloaded_fonts"
            android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".AlertReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: `String path = songCursor.getString(indexData);` Log the value of 'path'. Probably it is no valid path and 'null' instead. Or Toast() the value in onClick(). Or add another TextView to display path. Or put path as title or artist for a test.

Comment: Other Android version on used device as on emulator?

Comment: @blackapps I think so, i've tried the application on two real phones and it's not working but on most of emulators it works

Comment: @blackapps okay ill try that

Comment: @blackapps the path i get on real device always starts with /storage/emulated/0 and its the same for the emulator

Comment: Then it is time to mention Android versions of emulators and devices. And especially tell us on which Android versions it does not work. Well if that is the problem.

Comment: @blackapps android version on both of the real devices where this doesn't work is 10, android version on emulator where it works is 11

Comment: You should have told us that already when i asked: `Other Android version on used device as on emulator? `. Yes. On Android 10 you have no access to files on external storage. Well .. only when you did not request legacy external storage in manifest.

Comment: @blackapps i'll post my manifest file because i'm not sure what changes do i make

Comment: That does not very much look for a music app... I see that you did not request for legacy external storage ;-).

Comment: @blackapps it's not really a music app but i'm adding the music app to it lol and ohh okay i will request and see if it works

Comment: So you are now googling for request legacy external storage in manifest...

Comment: @blackapps sorry yeah i'm new to this, only been coding in android for three months however i've added the request and it works now thank you :)

Comment: I see you are in for a compliment.. well incredible... i would have needed three years for so many activities... and meanwhile my bmi would have raised...

Comment: @blackapps no that's not what i meant o.o just that i'm new and actually had to google what you mentioned xd and i mostly just watch videos and attach stuff